# Можно ли в форме обратной связи вместо инпута сделать оформление ссылкой для выбора файла?

Tags: html, css

Верстка формы такая:

```html
<form id="form-form-zayavka" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input class="w-input" id="name1" maxlength="256" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя?" required="required" type="text">
  <input class="w-input" id="phone1" maxlength="256" name="phone" placeholder="Как с вами связаться?" required="required"><a class="home-link-zayav" href="#" type="file">+прикрепить документ</a>
  <button class="home-sbt-zayav w-button" data-wait="Please wait..." type="button" value="Отправить спецификацию">Отправить спецификацию</button>
</form>
```

[image: скриншот формы]

Comment: не понятно что вы хотите, отправить файл вместо формы?

Comment: необходимо вместе с данными формы прикрепить файл и отправить на сервер. Инпут будет выглядеть некрасиво. Вопрос в том, можно ли при помощи тега <a> сделать загрузку файла.

Comment: так скройте инпут и js  вызовите диалоговое окно выбора файла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот примерно так можно реализовать:

```js
document.getElementById('upload_link').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('upload').click();
});
```

```css
#upload_link{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#upload{
    display:none
}
```

```html
<form id="form-form-zayavka" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input class="w-input" id="name1" maxlength="256" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя?" required="required" type="text">
  <input class="w-input" id="phone1" maxlength="256" name="phone" placeholder="Как с вами связаться?" required="required">
  <input id="upload" type="file"/>
  <a href="" id="upload_link">+прикрепить документ</a>
  <button class="home-sbt-zayav w-button" data-wait="Please wait..." type="button" value="Отправить спецификацию">Отправить спецификацию</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Сергей, большущее Вам спасибо! Очень сильно помогли!

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё так

```
#file-input {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* IE < 9 */
  opacity: 0;
}
.input-label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
<label for="file-input" class="input-label">
  Click Me <!-- Replace with whatever text or icon you wish to use -->
  <input type="file" id="file-input">
</label>
```

https://codepen.io/korolariya/pen/PJVeoV

Comment: спасибо большое!